# Tab is not working in MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tabs

In a MVC5 application I have in view 2 tabs with ids Main and Zones ad 2 divs with associated id Main and Zones:

```
<div class="tab-menu" data-rel="psDetails">
     <ul id="details">
       <li id="Main"><a href="#Main" >Main</a></li>
       <li id="Zones" ><a href="#Zones">Zones</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>

<div id="Main">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Parts/Main/MainPart.cshtml")
</div>
<div id="Zones">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Parts/Zones/ZonesPart.cshtml")
</div>
```

When I open the page the code from both tabs is shown and If I click on Main or Zones nothing happens. Can you help me to do this code works?

Comment: to catch events like clicking, you need javascript code; preferably using jquery. search for "handling clicks on html"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` to implement `tab`s in `MVC`.

Try this,

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Main">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Zones">Zones</a></li>
        </ul>

<div id="Main">
    //main div contents
</div>

<div id="Zones">
    //zone div contents
</div>

</div>
```

Then in `<script>` add the following.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
})
</script>
```

Refer `jQuery` files to your project.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/queryj/CnEUh/1/).

Answer (score 0):

As @schlingel writes you need some javascript to show/hide the div's
This will listen to the click event on the li's.

```
document.getElementById('main').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('maincontainer').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('zonescontainer').style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('zones').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('maincontainer').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('zonescontainer').style.display = 'block';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kx0mLkho/1/